# Plotly in R barchart labels cut off (RShiny example)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, bar-chart

I have this dataframe in R:

```
x <- c("apple", "mango", "pear")
male <- c(-0.1, 0.05, -0.3)
female <- c(-0.15, 0.02, -0.31)
data <- data.frame(x, male, female)
```

When I create a plot using plotly and I open it in the viewer, it looks good. I created the plot by:

```
the_plot <- data %>% plot_ly()


if (!all(is.na(male))) {
  the_plot <- the_plot %>% add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~male, type = "bar", text = paste0(round(male, digits=2),"%"), textposition = 'outside',
                                               marker = list(color = c("#007bc7")), name = "male")
}

if (!all(is.na(female))) {
  the_plot <- the_plot %>% add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~female, type = "bar", text = paste0(round(female, digits=2),"%"), textposition = 'outside', 
                                               marker = list(color = c("#ca005d")), name = "female")
}


the_plot <- the_plot %>% layout(title = list(text = paste0("the title: "),
                                                       x = 0.5, automargin = TRUE),
                                          yaxis = list(title = "% change in consumption", automargin = TRUE),
                                          xaxis = list(title = "", automargin = TRUE),
                                          margin = list(t = 50, b = 50))
```

However, as soon as I display it in my RShiny App the labels are being cut off. Now matter how I change the margins I can't prevent to either see the title or the barchart labels being cut off.

This is my code for the shiny app - ui:

```
 tabPanel("the title",
             fluidRow(
               column(6, plotlyOutput("theplot"))
             )
```

shiny app - server:

```
  output$theplot <- renderPlotly({
    the_plot <- results_process_data()$the_plot
    
    # Return the nutrient_plot if it's not NULL
    if (!is.null(the_plot)) {
      return(the_plot)
    }
  })
```

How can I prevent this from happening in all cases, no matter the data?

[image: labels cut off in RShiny app]

#### Reproducible Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

x <- c("apple", "mango", "pear")
male <- c(-0.1, 0.05, -0.3)
female <- c(-0.15, 0.02, -0.31)
data <- data.frame(x, male, female)

the_plot <- data %>% plot_ly()


if (!all(is.na(male))) {
  the_plot <- the_plot %>% add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~male, type = "bar", text = paste0(round(male, digits=2),"%"), textposition = 'outside',
                                     marker = list(color = c("#007bc7")), name = "male")
}

if (!all(is.na(female))) {
  the_plot <- the_plot %>% add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~female, type = "bar", text = paste0(round(female, digits=2),"%"), textposition = 'outside', 
                                     marker = list(color = c("#ca005d")), name = "female")
}


the_plot <- the_plot %>% layout(title = list(text = paste0("the title: "),
                                             x = 0.5, automargin = TRUE),
                                yaxis = list(title = "% change in consumption", automargin = TRUE),
                                xaxis = list(title = "", automargin = TRUE),
                                margin = list(t = 50, b = 50))

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("the title",
           fluidRow(
             column(6, plotlyOutput("theplot"))
           ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$theplot <- renderPlotly({
    the_plot <- the_plot
    
    # Return the nutrient_plot if it's not NULL
    if (!is.null(the_plot)) {
      return(the_plot)
    }
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I added a reproducible example at the end of your question. When I run this on my machine, the plotly looks fine in the shiny app. Maybe in your local version other elements of the app or your CSS styles are interfering with the plotly output?!

Comment: You reproducible example does not reproduce the problem. Even when reducing the display area to 150px, the title, label and chart display as expected.

Comment: Thank you Till and Guasi. Indeed the example doesn't reproduce the problem with cut-off labels. Therefore I think the issue must occur maybe do some interference indeed..

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by limiting the yaxis:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

x <- c("apple", "mango", "pear")
male <- c(-0.1, 0.05, -0.3)
female <- c(-0.15, 0.02, -0.31)
data <- data.frame(x, male, female)

the_plot <- data %>% plot_ly()


if (!all(is.na(male))) {
  the_plot <- the_plot %>% add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~male, type = "bar", text = paste0(round(male, digits=2),"%"), textposition = 'outside',
                                     marker = list(color = c("#007bc7")), name = "male")
}

if (!all(is.na(female))) {
  the_plot <- the_plot %>% add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~female, type = "bar", text = paste0(round(female, digits=2),"%"), textposition = 'outside', 
                                     marker = list(color = c("#ca005d")), name = "female")
}


the_plot <- the_plot %>% layout(title = list(text = paste0("the title: "),
                                             x = 0.5, automargin = TRUE),
                                yaxis = list(title = "% change in consumption", automargin = TRUE,
                                             range = c(-0.4, 0.1)),
                                xaxis = list(title = "", automargin = TRUE),
                                margin = list(t = 50, b = 50))

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel("the title",
           fluidRow(
             column(6, plotlyOutput("theplot"))
           ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$theplot <- renderPlotly({
    the_plot <- the_plot
    
    # Return the nutrient_plot if it's not NULL
    if (!is.null(the_plot)) {
      return(the_plot)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).